# react-jsonschema-form onSubmit reload

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I am using react-jsonschema-form to develop a form and I can not execute the function corresponding to the onSubmit button. I do not understand why it reloads the page when I press it and I do not execute the function.

```
const onSubmit = ({formData}) => console.log("Data submitted: ",  formData);

class QuestionsSet extends React.Component {

  render () {
    return (
      <section id="soyceliaco" className="section-padding text-justify">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">
              <h2 className="ser-title">Realizar cuestionario:</h2>
              <hr className="botm-line"></hr>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
              <Form schema={schemaQuestions}
                    onSubmit={onSubmit} >
              </Form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default QuestionsSet;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent default action like this

```
const onSubmit = ({formData},e) =>{ e.preventDefault(); console.log("Data submitted: ",  formData)};
```

works, if onsubmit generates an 'event'

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but continue to reload the page and without executing the function :(

Comment: is an 'event' generated as second or first argument?

Comment: I have no idea. I just follow the guide of the react-jsonschema-form package. https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form. Form submission
You can pass a function as the onSubmit prop of your Form component to listen to when the form is submitted and its data are valid. It will be passed a result object having a formData attribute, which is the valid form data you're usually after:

const onSubmit = ({formData}) => console.log("Data submitted: ",  formData);

render((
  <Form schema={schema}
        onSubmit={onSubmit} />
), document.getElementById("app"));